# Shared storage solution for Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, high-availability

I need to setup a new infrastructure which provides high available shared storage between debian servers.

Our current solution is a "clustered DRBD NFS solution". We have setup 2 virtual file servers and mirror the shared storage with drbd. We run NFS-Server (active/passive) on each fileserver. Other server mount the storage/shared folder via NFS. To control failover we use pacemaker/corosync.

Is this approach is still a good solution, or are there meanwhile better open source solutions e.g. with GlusterFS, etc?

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? Have you done any research on others?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can buy [SIOS Lifekeeper](http://us.sios.com/products/sps-linux/) which is similar to DRBD (network RAID), but handles the application, VIPs, failover/failback and is cluster-aware. It's basically a polished commercial solution for what you currently have.

Comment: I'm looking only for open source solutions

Comment: @markus Why? You did initially ask for "better" recommendations. What is the problem or pain-point with your current solution?

Comment: We has some problems with drbd from time to time, so I'm just interested if there are other solutions which are easier to manage and  more reliable.